# Constant Date and Time

Tags: ansible

I leverage this to get the date/time without running facts in my playbooks, in order to save run time:

all.yaml

```
date: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M\"') }}"
```

I've noticed that if I reference this at the beginning of the playbook it references one time e.g. 2019-04-10-1300.  If I reference it at the end of the playbook, which is 5 minutes later, the time is different e.g. 2019-04-10-1305.

I want to use this variable to reference a directory name, and therefore I want it to be constant from at any point in the script's lifetime.

```
 ./outputs/"{{ date }}"/errors.txt
```

AKA

```
 ./outputs/2019-04-10-1300/errors.txt
```

How do I get this value to be constant?

### EDIT

This task gives me an error

```
     - name: TESTS
      environment: 
        execution_date: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y%m%d-%H%M\"') }}"
      tags:
        - test
```

The group_var below is not callable via "environment.execution_date" or "execution_date"

all.yaml

```
environment:
  execution_date: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y%m%d-%H%M\"') }}"
```

```
    - name: TESTS
      debug:
        var: environment.execution_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're wanting to save/recall a particular date, using it like a variable.

Probably a few ways to do this, my first thought is that you could export this as an environment variable and then recall that value:

```
      environment:
        execution_date: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M\"') }}"
```

You would then use it like:

```
./outputs/"{{ execution_date }}"/errors.txt
```

Check out the documentation about this here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: Please see edit notes.  I can't get that to function.

Comment: Kyle, thank you for the response.  This solution works for setting the date within a play and referencing it in another, if the hosts are the same.  How can I set the date in the one play (for say "localhost") and and reference in play two which has different hosts?  If I were to set the date/time in play one and also set it in play two, its possible that the dates/times may be different.  This would break consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible variables don't store a value, they get re-evaluated each time they are referenced. Hence your `date` variable always does a fresh lookup of the current time.

To store a value, and recall it later you can set a fact, e.g.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        execution_time: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M\"') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ execution_time }}"
    - pause:
        minutes: 2

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ execution_time }}"
```