# Store Timestamp As A Constant Value

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to save the timestamp corresponding to when a playbook runs in a variable.
I plan to use this variable across the playbook but I'm facing issues particularly since
the lookup plugin runs and generates a new value each time.

```
  module_defaults:
    group/ns.col.session:
      sid: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M\"') }}"
```

The value is looked up at the time that it is invoked.

I could use `set_fact:` but it only works inside of the `tasks:` block and I'd like to set it to some value before any task can run i.e. right after hosts.

```
- hosts:
   - localhost

  module_defaults:
    group/ns.col.session:
      sid: .............
```

How do I achieve this WITHOUT using `set_fact` OR without using the `lookup()` ?
In other words, how to save or copy the value of a lookup to some variable ?

I've already reviewed [Constant Date and Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618402/constant-date-and-time)
but the solutions proposed over there do not satisfy my constraints.

The whole reason behind this is to not have any task run anywhere or modify the playbook to run a task on the Ansible Controller node alone, for looking up the timestamp but rather have it be preserved in a variable at the very beginning itself.

Comment: There was another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665576/ansible-timestamp-which-is-the-same-for-all-nodes-during-the-whole-play/69666540#69666540) recently.

Comment: You can send variables while running the `ansible-playbook` via the shell and can use that in the playbooks, like `ansible-playbook sample.yml -e timestamp=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")` and use timestamp within your playbooks.

Answer (score 0):

> ***I'd like to set it to some value before any task can run i.e. right after hosts. ... How do I achieve this WITHOUT using ... without using the `lookup()`?***

By [`gather_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) only when needed and using [`pre_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play). For more information see [Set the order of task execution in Ansible with these two keywords](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:

  - name: Gather date and time only
    delegate_to: controlnode.example.com # localhost
    run_once: true
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - "date_time"
        - "!min"
    when: ansible_date_time is not defined

  - name: Format timestamp as SID
    delegate_to: controlnode.example.com # localhost
    run_once: true
    set_fact:
      SID: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}-{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ SID }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [test] **************************************

TASK [Gather date and time only] *****************
ok: [test1.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]

TASK [Format timestamp as SID] *******************
ok: [test1.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]

TASK [debug] *************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: 2024-01-03-1000
ok: [test2.example.com] =>
  msg: 2024-01-03-1000

PLAY RECAP ***************************************
test1.example.com  : ok=3    
test2.example.com  : ok=1
```

**Similar Q&A and Further Reading**

- [Ansible timestamp which is the same for all nodes during the whole play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666260/6771046)
- [How to gather `ansible_facts` inside of a role only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use --extra-vars with your command. Extra vars has higher precedence and won't be overwritten so if you do not want to modify that value later it should work

```
TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
ansible-playbook your_playbook.yml --extra-vars "timestamp_var=$TIMESTAMP"
```

If passing extra vars is not an option then set it as an environmental variable and then use lookup inside the playbook