# How to gather ansible_facts inside of a role only when needed?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have this example role where I install some packages based on the OS and package manager:

```yaml
# THIS IS IN tasks/main.yml
- name: Ensure archlinux-keyring is updated
  community.general.pacman:
    name: archlinux-keyring
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "pacman"
```

If this role is run as part of a playbook, Ansible will gather the facts and everything is just fine. However, if I run it as a standalone role:

```bash
ansible localhost -m include_role -a name=examplerole
```

I get this error

```
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_pkg_mgr == \"pacman\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_pkg_mgr == \"pacman\"): 'ansible_pkg_mgr' is undefined
```

I know I can force Ansible to gather these facts inside the role, but  gathering facts over and over again will be super slow (as this is a recurring problem I have with several roles, and I can't always include them in a playbook, and also, if they ARE in a playbook, this isn't needed).

Is there any way to check if facts were already gathered, and gather them inside of the role only when needed?

Comment: If you use an ansible fact you need to gather it.
If you want to speed up the gather facts process you can use `memcache` or `redis` as caching mechanism to speed those tasks and activate the `gather_facts`.

What you can do is before that task have a task for gathering the facts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding

> *...Is there any way to check if facts were already gathered ... gather them inside of the role only when needed?*

and if you like to [gather facts based on conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) only, you may have a look into the following example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false

  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_facts }}"

  - name: Gather date and time only
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - "date_time"
        - "!min"
    when: ansible_date_time is not defined

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

which is gathering date and time only and if not defined before.

This means, regarding

> *gathering facts over and over again will be super slow*

it is recommended to get familiar with the data structure of the gathered facts and the possible subsets in order to gather only the information which is needed. And as well with [Caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts).

**Further Documentation**

- [`setup` module – Gathers facts about remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible setup min?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)