# Use an environment variable inside the lookup

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

My colleagues told me to not use `~` when I write paths, so I use instead the environment variable `$HOME`.

I have one task which works fine:

```yaml
ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
  path: $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
  [...]
```

On the other hand, this one fails:

```yaml
community.windows.win_lineinfile:
  line: "{{ lookup('file', '$HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub') }}"
  [...]
```

Is it not possible to use environment variables inside a `lookup`?

My current solution is:

```yaml
line: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('env', 'HOME')+'/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub') }}"
```

but it is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a 'cleaner' way to do this, I suggest that you use the `set_fact` module in order to save the `$HOME` `env` in a variable. Your code would become:

```yaml
- name: Save $HOME value
  set_fact:
    home: "lookup(''ansible.builtin.env', 'HOME')"

- name: Do your magic
  community.windows.win_lineinfile:
    line: "{{ lookup('file', {{ home }} + '/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A general approach could be just to `gather_facts` which are containing the environment variables of the Control Node if necessary and not available. To do so,

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Env Facts of Control Node only
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
    setup:
      gather_subset:
      - "env"
      - "!all"
      - "!min"
    when: ansible_facts.env is not defined

  - name: Show env.HOME
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.env.HOME }}"
```

**Further Reading**

- [Is it possible to gather only specific facts in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046)
- [How to gather `ansible_facts` inside of a role only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046)