# Run the date command on all hosts and save the output

Tags: ansible

I wrote a playbook that executes the date command on all hosts, but when I want to dump its output on a txt file, it only dumps the output of one of the hosts. If you could help me, I would be grateful.

```
---
- name: Check date output
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: date command
      shell: "date"
      register: date_output
      
    - debug: msg="{{inventory_hostname}}:{{ date_output.stdout }}"
    
    - name: Save the message in output.txt
      lineinfile:
            path: ./date.txt
            line: "{{inventory_hostname}}:{{ date_output.stdout }} \n"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: It is recommend to [`gather_facts` in order to get `ansible_date_time` for all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046). This can then become exported into a log if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you should use the date and time from gathering facts but if you really want to use the output from shell task this will work.

```
---
  - name: Get Server Date and time
    hosts:  "{{ hostgroup }}"
    gather_facts: false

    tasks:

    - name: date command
      shell: "date"
      register: date_output

    - name: Set date fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        dthost: "{{ date_output.stdout }}"

    - name: Generate report
      local_action:
        module: copy
        force: true
        dest: date.csv
        content: |
            Host,Date_Time
            {% for host in groups[hostgroup] %}
            {{ host }},{{ hostvars[host]['dthost'] }}
            {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

I pass in my hostgroup to all my playbooks so ajust accordingly for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of all hosts and their values of the variable *date_output.stdout*. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

Run the task

```yaml
    - command: date
      register: date_output
```

and declare the dictionary

```yaml
  dates: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                  zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                      map('extract', hostvars, ['date_output', 'stdout']))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dates:
    test_11: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
    test_13: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
```

Write it to the file on the controller

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/date.txt
        line: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ dates|dict2items }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/date.txt
test_11: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
test_13: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
```

When you run the play repeatedly the records will cumulate

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/date.txt
test_11: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
test_13: Fri Sep 22 07:03:45 UTC 2023
test_11: Fri Sep 22 07:09:01 UTC 2023
test_13: Fri Sep 22 07:09:01 UTC 2023
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    dates: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['date_output', 'stdout']))) }}"
  tasks:

    - command: date
      register: date_output
    - debug:
        var: date_output.stdout

    - debug:
        var: dates
      run_once: true

    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/date.txt
        line: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ dates|dict2items }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

**Module copy instead of lineinfile**

- The module *copy* overwrites the content of the file. In this case, the file will keep the last record only

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/date.txt
        content: |
          {% for host,date in dates.items() %}
          {{ host }}: {{ date }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

- Optionaly, you can create timestamps and link the last file

```yaml
    - block:

        - set_fact:
            timestamp: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'|strftime }}"

        - copy:
            dest: "/tmp/date.{{ timestamp }}"
            content: |
              {% for host,date in dates.items() %}
              {{ host }}: {{ date }}
              {% endfor %}

        - file:
            state: link
            src: "/tmp/date.{{ timestamp }}"
            dest: /tmp/date.txt

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

For example, gives (abridged)

```bash
shell> ls -l /tmp/date.*
/tmp/date.2023-09-22_13-38-53
/tmp/date.2023-09-22_13-38-58
/tmp/date.txt -> /tmp/date.2023-09-22_13-38-58
```